# Split row into two based and add new column based on dates in R

Tags: r, date, split, rows, generate

I've looked through stackoverflow and have seen different variations of what I need, but none that I can make work for me.

I have a large set of data comprising 116 columns and 326438 rows.

I need each row to be split into two, using the existing date fields as the calculation, with new date columns of 'StartDate' and 'EndDate' added.

If row 1 shows a PolicyEffectiveDate of 01/06/2018 and a PolicyRenewalDate of 01/06/2019 I need the data to reflect two rows with the following:

The first row would show StartDate of 01/06/2018 and the EndDate of 31/12/2018, the next row would show StartDate of 01/01/2019 and the EndDate of 31/05/2019. StartDate and EndDate being the new columns created in this process. All other data on the new row should match the first entry, in effect we are creating two rows out of 1 with all data matching apart from the two new fields that are to be created.

What I currently have is this:

```
PolicyEffectiveDate  PolicyRenewalDate  Customer
2017-06-01           2018-06-01         Arc Ltd
2017-04-03           2018-04-03         Windonian CC
```

What I need is this:

```
PolicyStartDate  PolicyEndDate  Customer
2017-06-01       2017-12-31     Arc Ltd
2018-01-01       2018-05-31     Arc Ltd
2017-04-03       2017-12-31     Windonian CC
2018-01-01       2018-04-02     Windonian CC
```

The code to make these two example df's is:

```
mydf <- data.frame(PolicyEffectiveDate = as.Date(c("2017-06-01", "2017-04-03")),
               PolicyRenewalDate = as.Date(c("2018-06-01", "2018-04-03")),
               Customer = as.character(c("Arc Ltd", "Windonian CC")),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

newdf <- data.frame(PolicyStartDate = as.Date(c("2018-06-01", "2019-01-01","2017-04-03", "2018-01-01")),
               PolicyEndDate = as.Date(c("2018-12-31", "2019-05-31","2017-12-31", "2018-04-02")),
               Customer = as.character(c("Arc Ltd","Arc Ltd", "Windonian CC","Windonian CC")),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: ```2017-06-01       2017-10-20     Arc Ltd``` What if you had a row like this? That will stay the same since Start and End are in one year? Or that would never be the case and policies will be always at least a year apart? Also what if you had ```2017-06-01       2019-09-10     Arc Ltd```, that would be 3 rows?

Comment: Hi, that's a great question. For this dataset the entry would typically be one year in length. 

It is possible to have a a shorter term, but it is rare and should be picked up by other work that I am carrying out with the data.

I suppose the only real excepetion would be a case that is from January the 1st, in that case just the one line would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ceiling_date` from `lubridate`:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(PolicyRenewalDate = ceiling_date(PolicyEffectiveDate, "y") - 1) %>%
    bind_rows(mutate(df, 
                     PolicyEffectiveDate = .$PolicyRenewalDate + 1,
                     PolicyRenewalDate = PolicyRenewalDate - 1
                     )) %>%
    arrange(Customer) %>%
    rename(PolicyStartDate = PolicyEffectiveDate, 
           PolicyEndDate = PolicyRenewalDate)

#### OUTPUT ####

  PolicyStartDate PolicyEndDate     Customer
1      2017-06-01    2017-12-31      Arc Ltd
2      2018-01-01    2018-05-31      Arc Ltd
3      2017-04-03    2017-12-31 Windonian CC
4      2018-01-01    2018-04-02 Windonian CC
```

Comment: @Saarek I've modified the answer slightly to better reflect your desired output. For instance, you subtract a day from from some of your end dates, and you change the variable names. It looks a little less elegant, but it's more accurate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, genuinely appreciated.